# Expressing trigonometric expression in multiple angles using complex methods.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How would you express $\cos^3x\sin^3x$ in terms of $\sin(6x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ via complex methods?

Comment: One thing that I would *not* do would be to post that here, without context and with no display of effort, and expect that someone else would do the whole work for me.

Comment: Does "complex methods" have a specific meaning for you?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "via complex methods" , but it is possible to write $\cos^3(x) \sin^3(x)$ in terms of $\sin(6x)$ and $\sin(2x)$ using normal conversions

Comment: I'd assume that 'complex methods' means a method involving complex numbers, given the complex numbers tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos^3x\sin^3x=\frac{1}{8}\sin^32x$$
Now that we have that, we can use complex numbers to derive an identity for this in terms of $\sin6x$ and in $\sin2x$ (assuming you mean a method using complex numbers when you say 'complex methods'). Firstly, note that of $z=\cos x+i\sin x$, then $z^2-z^{-2}=2i\sin2x$ and in general, $z^n-z^{-n}=2i\sin nx$.

Hence, $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{8}\sin^32x&=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{z^2-z^{-2}}{2i}\right)^3=-\frac{1}{64i}(z^6-3z^2+3z^{-2}-z^{-6})\\
&=-\frac{1}{64i}(2i\sin6x-6i\sin2x)=\frac{3}{32}\sin2x-\frac{1}{32}\sin6x\end{align}$$

---

I hope that was helpful. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by "via complex methods". But this is a relatively simple conversion, by usual methods.

\begin{eqnarray} \cos^3(x)\sin^3(x) &=& \bigl(\cos(x)\sin(x)\bigr)^3
\\ &=& \Biggl(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\Biggr)^3 
\\ &=& \frac{1}{8}\sin^3(2x) 
\\ &=& \frac{1}{8}\Biggl(\frac{1}{4}\biggl(3\sin(2x) - \sin(6x)\biggr)\Biggr) 
\\ &=& \frac{1}{32}\Biggl(3\sin(2x) - \sin(6x)\Biggr)\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I was referring to using complex number methods. But I think the first half of your solution is what I didn't realize, even though it's so obvious.